# NSLengthFormatter not displaying correct value

Tags: ios, ios8, nsformatter

So in **iOS 8** there were some formatters added such as: `NSEnergyFormatter`, `NSMassFormatter` and `NSLengthFormatter`. Those formatters are supposed to confirm to user's locale set in settings.

So I have this code:

```
NSLengthFormatter *formatter = [[NSLengthFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *converted = [formatter stringFromValue:24.0 unit:NSLengthFormatterUnitInch];

NSLog(@"%@", converted);
```

This code outputs `24 in`, even though my locale is set to **Slovenian**, which I think should display the length in metric system.

*The code seems fine to me and I don't really understand why this is not outputing the value in metric system.*

The documentation is apparently not yet done: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFormatter_Class/

**What exactly is the point of the formatter, if it does no conversion?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For converting units, I think, `NSLengthFormatter` only accepts [SI unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units) length, in particular, "Meter".

For example (in Swift):

```
let formatter = NSLengthFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en-US")
formatter.stringFromMeters(0.5)
```

results `"1.64 ft"`

`stringFromValue:unit:` is to display "unit" string for locale.

```
let formatter = NSLengthFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "fr-FR")
formatter.unitStyle = NSFormattingUnitStyle.Long
formatter.stringFromValue(12.0, unit: NSLengthFormatterUnit.Inch);
```

results `"12 pouces"`

**UPD:**

I think, these new `NSFormatter` subclasses are mainly targeted to work with "HealthKit" framework.
Actually, `HealthKit` has unit conversion capability.

Try this in Playground:

```
import HealthKit

// input value
let foot = HKUnit.footUnit()
let footQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: foot, doubleValue: 1.23)

// to convert unit
let mm = HKUnit(fromString: "mm")
let mmVal = footQuantity.doubleValueForUnit(mm) // -> 374.904
let mmQuantity = HKQuantity(unit: mm, doubleValue: mmVal)

// coordinate with formatter
let formatter = NSLengthFormatter()
let mmFormat = HKUnit.lengthFormatterUnitFromUnit(mm)
formatter.numberFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "sl-SI")
formatter.stringFromValue(mmVal, unit: mmFormat) // -> "374,904 mm"
```

Comment: But I have the data in ft, not meters, so I need to convert from ft to meters and vice versa.

Comment: Yeah, but this is not really a HealthKit app right now (might be in the future though). So can I only use this conversion from HK without actually having HealthKit entitlements?

Comment: Yes, you can use the unit and converter classes from HealthKit, aka HKUnit, HKQuantity, without HealthKit entitlements for your project.